# SYmfony 2 apc error

Tags: php, caching, symfony, apc

I'm using symfony 2 and when i'm launching my app in production mode, i'm getting this error

```
ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved

While trying to retrieve the URL: http://noupei.com/

The following error was encountered:

    Zero Sized Reply 

Squid did not receive any data for this request.

Your cache administrator is root.
```

Now when i check error log, i see the following:

```
[apc-error] Cannot redeclare class noupei\websitebundle\dependencyinjection\noupeiwebsiteextension in /var/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/PhpFileLoader.php on line 42.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your app.php file and search the line:

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);

and change for

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);